# Routing not working in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Routing in my app is setup as follows:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
  });

  $stateProvider
  .state('app.todos', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      todos: {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'TodosCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider
  .state('app.help', {
    url: '/help',
    views: {
      help: {
        templateUrl: 'help.html'    
      }
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

//index.html

```
<body>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"> </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab icon="ion-checkmark" ui-sref="app.todos">
      <ion-nav-view name="todos"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="ion-help" ui-sref="app.help">
      <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>


  </ion-tabs>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <ion-view title="Todos">
      <ion-content padding="true">
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Here's the main route for the app.</p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="help.html">
  <ion-view title="Help">
    <ion-content padding="true">
       <h2>Using the app</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis architecto hic officia quasi excepturi sequi deleniti maiores consectetur veritatis sint?</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

</body>
```

On app start, I would expect the state app.todos to become active and display the respective template.

This is not happening.

Plnkr available here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/LDNLHx?p=preview

Comment: How are you linking to that route?  I thought I noticed an invalid anchor tag...could you show us the code that would link to the friends page?

Comment: not sure if you have opened the right plnkr

Comment: Go ahead and post your tabs.html file here, I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: it's in the plnkr..all relevant files

Comment: So the reason I'm asking you to post it here is because that Plunkr may disappear...and there's something *very relevant* in that specific file (which is why you don't need to post the entire thing here).

Comment: I've seen a trend of people ignoring questions when there are huge chunks of code in them.. I get better responses when i simply provide them with a semi-working plnkr...  anyways I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this codepen http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/wKMEYP?editors=101

I moved the tabs template out to an HTML file and structured it how I am use to working with tabs and it seems to be working fine.

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tabs.html">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
      <ion-tab icon="ion-checkmark" ui-sref="app.todos">
        <ion-nav-view name="todos"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab icon="ion-help" ui-sref="app.help">
        <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </script>
```

I also restructured your abstract state to handle the new structure

```
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "tabs.html"
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Put names of views under the quotes.

> views: {
>         'todos': {
>           templateUrl: 'home.html',
>           controller: 'TodosCtrl'
>         }
>       }